# Expiry Date for Signature

Tags: web3js, signature, cryptography

I am signing an arbitrary string by

```
const ts = Date.now();
const hash = await web3.utils.sha3(anystring+ts);
const sign = await web3.eth.personal.sign(hash, account);
```

and check the address by

```
const address = await web3.eth.accounts.recover(hash, sign);
```

The problem is, that this signature is valid forever.

How is it possible to introduce and expiry date/time?

Comment: The signature will always be the same. You can do `await web3.utils.sha3(anystring+ts+Date.now().toString());` to get a different value based on time.

Comment: I do add the timestamp in order to get different hashes and signatures. The API backend uses recover(hash, signature) in order to identify the user. So, if anyone is in possession of any hash/signature pair of a user, he/she can call the API on behalf of that user. Therefore, I am not sure, if an invalidation or expiry mechanism is required (nonce?).

Comment: Do you send `anystring` back to server?

Comment: to produce the signature you need the private key, and nobody except the owner can send the signature. So you must make your code to process data related to  signing account only and not other accounts. This way it doesn't matter who sends the signature on behalf of the original sender

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a nonce + expiry time on the backend, store it on your DB and send the nonce to the frontend for signing.

This way you'll be able to validate the signed nonce on the backend, then check your DB for expiry time.

Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.toptal.com/ethereum/one-click-login-flows-a-metamask-tutorial#why-the-login-flow-works) and diagram -

[image]