# Signature with expiry date/time / deadline

Tags: web3js, signature, recover

I need to `sign()` and `recover()` in web3js. How can I add and expiry data/time to the signature and how to handle the `recover()` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at these two resources on how to assign an expiry date and handle the `recover()` in signatures.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68265812/expiry-date-of-signature

[Expiry Date for Signature](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103065/expiry-date-for-signature)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
const hashString = web3.utils.sha3(string);
const deadline = Math.round(Date.now()/1000)+period; //+period in sec
const hashStringAndDeadling = web3.utils.sha3(hashString+deadline);
const sign = web3.eth.accounts.sign(hashStringAndDeadline [, privKey]);
```

I send `hashString`, `deadline`and the `sign` to the application to check.
There I check the `deadline`and

```
const hash = web3.utils.sha3(hashString+deadline)
if(web3.eth.accounts.recover(hash, sign) == address {}
```